# How to get python script to reconnect with IBKR TWS API? The 5pm ET disconnect almost always kills the script

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

I'm using TWS 985.1d offline version, IB_insync 0.9.66 and have IBC Alpha 3.87 to have TWS automatically reconnect.

I run my script 4am ET premarket all the way till 8pm post market.

TWS seems to consistently disconnect around 8.40am ET and around 5pm ET, but it's the latter that almost always kills my script. The script somehow handles the 8.40am ET disconnect fine.

Recently I found one clue but still not sure how to handle it.

Looking at the screenshot below, my script still pumps out scanner notifications to my Telegram chat when the disconnect starts at 5.17pm ET. This seems to indicate my script is still running, even if the scanner ticker list output looks looped with duplicate add-ons.

But at 05:26 the logs states TWS is reconnected (apologies for the incomplete screenshot but that 05:26 log is indeed a reconnect even though it looks similar to previous rows), the script stops sending scanner updates, and just freezes.

[image]

Here is a full screenshot of the error logs and the messages. There were no more errors generated after that message saying IB and TWS successfully reconnected.

[image]

My script is using the following line to initiate the connection.

```
# init IB client
try:
    #util.startLoop()  # uncomment this line when in a notebook
    ib = IB()
    ib.connect(host=config.host, port=config.port, clientId=config.clientId)
except Exception as e:
    print('error connecting to IB API -', e)
    msg = f'error connecting to IB API - {e}'
    alerts.ibdisconnect(msg) # modification
    quit(0)
```

I also have exception handling at the start of the while loop.

```
While True:
    try:
        ib.sleep(0.5)
        while not ib.isConnected():
            ib = IB()
            ib.sleep(60) # modification
            ib.connect() 
        if scan_data.new_scan_results:
            scan_data.new_scan_results = False
            console_print('\n Updated Scanner streams ')
```

and another block at the end of the loop.

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        shutdown = True
        break
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(e)
        while not ib.isConnected():
            ib = IB()
            ib.sleep(60) # modification
            ib.connect()
```

How do I resolve this? I have tried extending that ib.sleep from (2) seconds to (60) seconds but it still does not reconnect.

Previously I had not noticed that my script was actually still running throughout the disconnect, but now that it seems isolated that the script freezes upon reconnection, is there something I should do with those 3 blocks above to attempt reconnection?

Comment: This is the second question on re-connecting.  Here's the other one, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67472229/2855515   Note, in 20 years I've never lost a connection from my api program to TWS so have never needed to implement any logic to re-connect.  TWS often loses connection to IB's servers but TWS will try to re-connect, that sometimes fails and your api needs to handle that situation but there's nothing you can do except quit.

Comment: There is one situation when a connection gets lost between your program and TWS and that's if your program throws an exception and it's not handled, but you should see an exception in a log or console for your program.  Note these comments are if TWS and the api program are on the same computer.  It's possible to run them separately on  a network and keep unplugging the ethernet cable.

Comment: hi @brian thanks for your input. Wow how did you code your connection, do you mind sharing? Or from the relevant code blocks i shared, is there anything I could have done? About my program throwing an exception, it appears there was none, other than the IB and TWS error messages in the log. I updated post with the screenshot.

Comment: forgot to add, i'm using ib_insync 0.9.66.

Comment: In all my programs I now use java but years ago it was vb.  You can see in IB's source code if there is an exception then disconnect() is called.  My connection code is just copied from IB's examples.  I have never made any re-connect logic.  I don't see how a connection can ever be broken on programs running on the same machine without there being some kind of exception that closes the socket.  Maybe ask at https://groups.io/g/insync/messages    ib_insync may do something different.

Comment: I couldn't read your screen shots, but zooming in on the bottom one shows that you haven't lost a connection to TWS, TWS has lost a connection to IB which happens all the time.  There is no need to re-connect your program to TWS.  If the scanner isn't working just cancel it and subscribe again (use a different reqId just to be sure).

Comment: As @brian stated, these errors are nothing to do with you. Your TWS/Gateway loses connection with IB due to a daily reset. There's no way around it but you can change the time by going with another regional server farm (IB has NY, Illinois, CH and HK to choose from). Each region has different reset periods.